# how to allow input type number to accept alphabet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to enter full width number and turn it into half width using jquery but first I need it to accept characters that are not number.

```
<input id="text1" step="0.5" type="number" value="" name="text1">
```

I need type number because I want the step feature.

Comment: What is "full width number " and "half width number" ?

Comment: Please post a sample of the inputs to create a [mcve]

Comment: Need a context here

Comment: Assuming that by "full width number" you mean characters in the range U+FF10 - U+FF19, just remove the `type` attribute from the `input`. Or if you can't change the HTML, then since you're dependent on jQuery anyway, you can just use jQuery to remove the `type` attribute.

Comment: removing type attribute will make the step attribute obsolete. why the downvote tho ,no one even gives a substantial help and still downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a `type="number"` field accept non-numeric characters. If you want to do that, you'll need to use `type="text"`. (If you need the step feature, you'll have to implement it.)

Comment: Thanks, this is the only answer I am looking for. I was actually hesitant but thanks for reassuring it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your text filed to accept floating numbers. Use following Input.

```
<input  type="number" step="any" name="text1" value="">
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I never said anything that I need to accept floating numbers. I said I need to accept alphabet characters into the type number , if it is not possible then I will close this question.